# chef vs MSDeploy- An analysis

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, chef-infra, msdeploy, continuous-deployment

I have gone through articles on how to implement MSdeploy which is a Microsoft web deployment tool and also chef cookbooks. Most of the windows servers have [msdeploy](/questions/tagged/msdeploy) installed by default but for chef we need to manually install and configure the chef-repo.

We have few web application which needs to be auto deployed. Each application varies in size and configuration. So what is the criteria to select MSdeploy and chef?  E.g., for small application with less configuration, can we just select MSdeploy?

What is the advantage of chef over MSdeploy or in which scenario can I go for chef?   Does chef provide any extra features which MSdeploy not provides?

Which is the better approach?

Comment: StackOverflow unfortunately does not allow these kinds of open-ended, opinion-based questions as they do not fit our model. I would recommend asking on the respective mailing lists for each project or try community hubs like Twitter, Reddit, or HackerNews.

Comment: There is no one-size-fits-all tool.  Chef will be better in some environments, but MSDeploy may be preferable in another, for any number of reasons.  Asking for an evaluation without that context is just asking for opinions, and doesn't help you come up with the best tool for your actual environment.

Comment: Could you pls check the updated answer and let me know whether I missed some other information which prevents you from answer this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chef and MSDeploy are not equivalent tools.

Chef if a configuration management tool. it is used to configure and maintain servers. A chef recipe could  for example define that the Web Server Role is installed on a server and that certain features of that role are available. This promotes consistency between environments and server types. If you have 500 web servers you want to make sure they are all configured exactly the same then tools like chef are invaluable.

MSDeploy is a tool for deploying (web) applications to a server. It cannot ensure consistency of the OS / Environment. Only push application code to the file system and configure IIS.

Answer (score 1):

We currently use MSDeploy to deploy 50+ applications/systems.  We are starting to  create Chef scripts to handle configuration of the server.  We plan on continuing to use MSDeploy for application deployment.  Chef will be used to ensure we don't have configuration drift of the server configuration over time.